# `edge from child` in trees

Tags: tikz-trees

I have a tree like below:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,arrows}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[edge from parent/.style={draw,-latex}]
    \node [draw=none] (q0) {$q_r$}
    child {node [draw=none] (q2) {$q_0$}
            child {node [draw=none] (q4) {$q_1$}
                child {node [draw=none] (q7) {$q_4$}
                    child {node [draw=none] (q10) {$q_s$}}
                      }
                child {node [draw=none] (q8) {$q_5$}
                    child {node [draw=none] (q10) {$q_s$}}
                      }
                  edge from parent [->] node [left] {$\sigma_1$}
                  }
            child {node [draw=none] (q5) {$q_2$}
                child {node [draw=none] (q10) {$q_s$}}
                  }
            child {node [draw=none] (q5) {$q_3$}
                child {node [draw=none] (q10) {$q_s$}}
                  }
          };
    \node[] at (-0.70,-3) {$\times$};
    \node[] at (0.70,-3) {$\times$};
    \node[] at (-1.5,-4.45) {$\times$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What I need is labeling all edges and setting all edge directions from children to parents. I tried to change `edge from parent` to `edge from child` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- to reverse edge direction use `edge from parent/.style={draw,latex-}`

off-topic:

- all nodes' options `[draw=none]` are superfluous
- nodes `$\times$` can be integrated to the tree as `child {node {$\times$} edge from parent[draw=none]}`

[image]

*mwe*:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
edge from parent/.style={draw,latex-},
sibling distance = 9mm,
                    ]
\node (q0) {$q_r$}
child {node (q2) {$q_0$}
        child {node (q4) {$q_1$}
            child {node (q7) {$q_4$}
                child   {node (q10) {$q_s$} edge from parent node[left]{$\gamma_1$}
                        } edge from parent node[left]{$\delta_1$}
                  }
            child {node {$\times$} edge from parent[draw=none]}
            child {node (q8) {$q_5$}
                child   {node (q10) {$q_s$} edge from parent node[right]{$\gamma_2$}
                        }   edge from parent node[right]{$\delta_2$}
                  } edge from parent node[left]{$\sigma_1$}
              }
        child {node {$\times$} edge from parent[draw=none]}
        child {node  (q5) {$q_2$}
            child   {node  (q10) {$q_s$} edge from parent node[right]{$\delta_3$}
                    } edge from parent node[left]{$\sigma_2$}
              }
        child {node {$\times$} edge from parent[draw=none]}
        child   { node (q5) {$q_3$}
            child   {node (q10) {$q_s$} edge from parent node[right]{$\delta_4$}
                } edge from parent node[right]{$\sigma_3$}
              }
       edge from parent node[right] {$\sigma_0$}
      };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**edit:**
for labeling of edges is intended `edge from parent node [<where>] {<label>}`. for labeling edge between parent and child it should be placed after child node. see improved mwe above

Comment: Thanks. Can you please also mention how I should add labels to the edges? Like the one which is commented in your MWE?

Comment: @A.Loc, sorry, i didn't figured out what is purpose of this code line. i add label.

Comment: Thanks. What I need is actually the best way to add the labels to "all" edges. If you kindly add one, I'll find out the method.

Comment: @A.Loc, see edited answer. now i add labels to all edges in your tree.